# obtaining info about facebook likes - strange issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I've developed some facebook application (wrote in php) that should allow users to use it only if they liked some fanpage.

Everything worked good till today when i received some feedback from users about blocked access to the application.

It seems like application doesnt let them in because they didnt liked the fanpage, but the point is that those users already like that fanpage (I tested it many times).

Im checking if user like a fanpage with the standard graph request like `/USER_ID/likes?target_id=PAGE_ID`

This mostly returns some array if user likes that page or empty array if he doesnt. In my case for those users it was always empty array.

I also checked `/USER_ID/likes` - for list of all likes of user, and for normal users i got response with json array of pages they like, in case of "bugged" users i again got empty array.

Im using PHP with phpsdk, so all requests are made with `$facebook->api(...)`

I have like 2 users with that problem now, others are fine.

I'm not sure if im doing something wrong or it is some of facebook bug.

I would be glad to hear opinion about that of anyone experienced with facebook api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be from the user not authorizing the app to access the user information. You can use the signed request from the Facebook API to see if the user has liked the page, which will be much more reliable.

```
require 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "app_id";
$app_secret = "app_secret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if($signed_request["page"]["liked"] != 1) { 
    // Render the blocker page
}else{
    // Business as usual
}
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but i though the `$signed_request["page"]["liked"]` returns true when user likes application, not a fanpage. I need to check if he likes specified fanpage not an application.

Comment: That variable is used for the fanpage and not for the application itself.